# NestJS -- JWT Dependency is not being loaded

Tags: node.js, nestjs, jwt

I do not need complete passport, I just need to sign a JWT token.

I tried working with this [repository](https://github.com/nestjs/jwt)
I tried all possible combinations, but I just cant integrate it in the project. I had followed the course of several different errors. I fix one, and the another pops up. So, I am including minimum part, and the current error that is thrown.

**AuthModule:**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';

@Module({
  imports: [ JwtModule.register({ secret: 'hard!to-guess_secret' })],
  providers: [AuthService],
  exports: [AuthService, JwtService]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**AuthService:**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from '../users/users.service';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
      private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}

  async signPayload (user: any) {
    const payload = { username: 'HARDCORE', color:'RED' };
    return {
      whatever: this.jwtService.sign(payload),
    };
  }
}
```

AppModule:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        secret: 'wefwefwef',
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      ...
    }),
    UsersModule,
    SubscriptionsModule,
    ProductsModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**SomeController:**

```
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService,
              private readonly authService: AuthService
  ) {}
...
 @ApiResponse({ status: 401, description: 'Unauthorized.' })
  @ApiResponse({ status: 404, description: 'User Not Found.' })
  @Get('users')
  async findOne(@Query() userGetDto: UserGetDto): Promise<User> {
    const user = await this.usersService.findByUsername(userGetDto.userName);
    if (!user) throw new NotFoundException('User Not Found')
     let signedUser = this.authService.signPayload(user);
    return user;
```

And this is the error with this setup that I get:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JwtService (?). Please make
> sure that the argument JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS at index [0] is available in
> the JwtService context.

I spend lot of time on this one, but I just cant make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your error, `JwtService` is in an `imports` array somewhere. Providers (classes marked with `@Injectable()`) never go in the `imports` array, but rather should be added to the `exports` array and that module where the `exports` was added should be put in the consuming module's `imports` array.

Also, if you are working with a Dynamic Module (any module that uses `register` or `forRoot` or an async variant of the two) you should always export the module instead of its services, as the module most likely has important configurations necessary for the service to work.

Comment: I found a problem. I will post my solution in hopes it helps someone. It seems this is pretty regular issue for users.